How to acount for heteroskedasticity when using survey package?
I'm performing a linear regression analysis using the European Social Survey. The ESS requires weighting, so I'm using the svyglm-function from the survey package. The  residuals vs. fitted values plot for the base model indicated some form of heteroskedasticity.
My question: How can I account for heteroskedasticity in this context? Normally I would use hetoskedasticity-robust standard errors via the coeftest function. Does this also work with survey glm models?
I tried to do this with the following line. mod1_aut_wght is the svyglm object, which I calculated before
coeftest(mod1_aut_wght, vcov = vcovHC(mod1_aut_wght, type = "HC3"))

I actually do get a result and p values change. However I also get the following warning message: "In logLik.svyglm(x) : svyglm not fitted by maximum likelihood." The message makes sense, because I did not specify any non-linear model type in the svyglm-function. Is this a problem here and is my method the correct way?
Thanks for every advice in advance!
